# Excel VBA - Complex nested if/then issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that I am altering to run daily reports that show various stats about employees including their login time.

What this code did before I altered it was looped through a column containing login times.  If the time was greater than 8 hours and 28 minutes, it ignored it.  if the column was between 0 and 8:28, it prompted me to say yes or no as to whether or not the "short time" was approved, and highlighted accordingly.  Finally, if the employee was not there at all that day, it highlighted the entire row in grey.

As I generally let people do shorter days on Friday, I am updating the code so that I do not have to constantly tell the code to mark everyone for approve short time.  I want the code to ask me if the report is for Friday.  If it is not, it is to move to the old snippet of code.  If it is, it then prompts me to enter then number of working hours for that day (everyone is assumed to have worked the same amount of time).  It then proceeds with asking about short time.

It appears that my logic is basically correct, however, the highlighting is not working right now for both parts of the code.  In the "old code", whether or not I mark the short time as approved, it still highlights red (5263615).  In the new code, no matter what, it highlights grey (11711154).  I assume it is something simply missing, but I cannot find it.

```
'Account for any OOO
    Dim int1 As Integer, int2 As Integer, workHours As Variant, scheduledOff As Range
    Dim dayPrompt As String, stPrompt As String
    dayPrompt = "Is this report for a Friday?"
    int1 = MsgBox(dayPrompt, vbYesNo)
    If int1 = vbYes Then
        workHours = InputBox("Enter the number of working hours for the day")
        For Each scheduledOff In Range("H2:H8")
            If scheduledOff.Value > 0 And scheduledOff.Value < (workHours) Then
                Cells(scheduledOff.Row, 1).Resize(, 1).Interior.Color = 13382655
                stPrompt = "Was the highlighted analyst scheduled to be short time?"
                int2 = MsgBox(stPrompt, vbYesNo)
                    If int1 = vbYes Then
                        scheduledOff.FormatConditions.Delete
                        scheduledOff.Interior.Color = 11711154
                    Else
                        scheduledOff.FormatConditions.Delete
                        scheduledOff.Interior.Color = 5263615
                    End If
                Cells(scheduledOff.Row, 1).Resize(, 1).Interior.Color = 16777215
            ElseIf scheduledOff.Value = 0 Then
                Cells(scheduledOff.Row, 1).Resize(, 20).FormatConditions.Delete
                Cells(scheduledOff.Row, 1).Resize(, 20).Interior.Color = 11711154
            End If
        Next scheduledOff
    ElseIf int1 = vbNo Then
        For Each scheduledOff In Range("H2:H8")
            If scheduledOff.Value > 0 And scheduledOff.Value < TimeValue("8:28:00") Then
                Cells(scheduledOff.Row, 1).Resize(, 1).Interior.Color = 13382655
                stPrompt = "Was the highlighted analyst scheduled to be short time?"
                int2 = MsgBox(stPrompt, vbYesNo)
                    If int1 = vbYes Then
                        scheduledOff.FormatConditions.Delete
                        scheduledOff.Interior.Color = 11711154
                    Else
                        scheduledOff.FormatConditions.Delete
                        scheduledOff.Interior.Color = 5263615
                    End If
                Cells(scheduledOff.Row, 1).Resize(, 1).Interior.Color = 16777215
            ElseIf scheduledOff.Value = 0 Then
                Cells(scheduledOff.Row, 1).Resize(, 20).FormatConditions.Delete
                Cells(scheduledOff.Row, 1).Resize(, 20).Interior.Color = 11711154
            End If
        Next scheduledOff
    End If
```

Comment: Er, wow, try breaking out your code into smaller pieces and unit testing each of them individually.

Comment: wouldn't that be easier with a rule for *conditional formatting* and a helper column for approved/non-approved than using VBA?

Comment: Add a break point and step through your code.  Make sure the values are what you think they are.  That's going to be the quickest way to debug, otherwise we'd just be guessing what the value of scheduledOff.Value is for each iteration

Comment: you are still testing `int1` when you should be testing `int2` on the inner if.

Comment: Maybe something with the format of your inputbox? Also have a look on int1 and int2. What about using the same loop (and ifs) for all days and only set different workHours?

Comment: Click this link to [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) (including how to _step_ through code).  Also, check out [mcve]

Comment: Yes, the issue was with the int1/int2.  Once I added the new int, I changed the original first one to a 2, but I didn't catch it's location inside the loop.  Ugh.  Thank you all for your assistance!